# get_post_feature_image($post_id) not working

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api

I'm a newbie to working with WordPress and I don't work a lot with PHP and I don't have a lot of time to see this through so please if anyone knows whats causing the problem here it would be much appreciated. Here's the functions.php code :

```
function get_post_feature_image($post_id){
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'=>1,
        'order'=>'asc',
        'post_mime_type'=>'image',
        'post_parent'=>$post_id,
        'post_type'=>'attachment',
        );

$attachments = get_children($args);
return wp_get_attachment_image_src(array_values($attachments)[0]->ID, 'app-thumb')[0];

}
```

and its called here to get the post image :

```
function get_post_by_id($request) { 
    $post = get_post($request["id"]);
    $post_categories = wp_get_post_categories($post->ID);
    $post_output = (object)array(
        "id"=> $post->ID,
        "post_date"=> $post->post_date,
        "title"=>$post->post_title,
        "category_name"=>get_category($post_categories[0])->name, 
        "post_content"=>$post->post_content,
        "imageurl"=>get_post_feature_image($post->ID) // <== here 
    );

    $response = new WP_REST_Response($post_output);
    $response->set_status(200);
    
    return $response;
    
}
```

[image: heres the 1st element of the response when calling latest-posts?category_id=33]

[image: and heres the the response when calling post-details?id=5692]

It doesn't return any image in the second response but in the first it return some form of ad banned thing.

I don't know what to try because I searched everywhere and the function "should" be working but its not.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you are not using correct function:

Use this instead:

[get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID)](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/)